# Cloud service for outbound call messaging

Tags: api, messaging, voip, voice

I would like to integrate a service as. Apart of our product signin that will call the user to give them a code.

I can generate codes as mp3 without issue but I don't know of a service that can place the call and then play the mp3 to the user.

Any thoughts or feedback on this sort of app need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly recommend Twilio Cloud Communication, it can be used to send the code via SMS or by a phone call.

Using PHP as an example, here is how it would look -

**Text Message**

```
<?php
// Get the Twilio PHP Library from http://twilio.com/docs/libraries
require "Services/Twilio.php";

//Random Code
$code = rand(pow(10, 6-1), pow(10, 6)-1);

// Set your Twilio Account settings
$AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

//Initial Twilio instance
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

//Recipient number - must be +15555555555 format
$recipient = '+18882224444';
$caller_id = '+18008885555'; //Twilio phone number

//Send the message
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
    $caller_id,
    $recipient,
    "Your activation code is: $code"
);
```

**Phone Call**

```
<?php
// Get the Twilio PHP Library from http://twilio.com/docs/libraries
require "Services/Twilio.php";

// Set your Twilio Account settings
$AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

//Initial Twilio instance
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
    '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
    '8881231234', // Call this number

    //When the call is connected, code at this URL will be executed
    '/say-code.php'
);
```

**say-code.php**

```
<?php
// Get the Twilio PHP Library from http://twilio.com/docs/libraries
require "Services/Twilio.php";
// Random Code
$code = rand(pow(10, 6-1), pow(10, 6)-1);

// Generate TwiML - XML for Twilio
// This will execute when the caller is connected and use Text-To-Speech to
// play their activation code.
// You may also use an MP3 like so:
// $response->play('http://example.com/code.mp3');
$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
$response->say("Your activation code is $code");
print $response;
```

There are a lot of other helper libraries out there to accomplish this with Twilio. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if something like Twilio Cloud Communications would work.